# execute javascript before dom is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to develop a handle javascript class that handle used frameworks, among other things.

For example:

```
myClass.addFramework('jQuery'); // just an example
```

It works fine and my class add the framework - but if there any jQuery code in it, it wouldn't work, because the framework is loaded after the dom is ready, so a default jQuery snippet like `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});` can't work, because 'jQuery' isn't already defined.

Is there any solution to that I can script a 'fix' that before the rest of the dom is beginning to loading all my `addFramework` methods must be executed ?

Comment: Or maybe a fix that javascript be ignored until my methodes are executed

Comment: If your code uses jQuery, all you have to do is ensure that jQuery is loaded *before* your code. (Load jQuery in an earlier SCRIPT element.) That has nothing to do with the DOM-ready event btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the onload event while creating `script` tag. You can use like this:

```js
myClass.addFramework('jQuery', function () {
    // do stuff after jquery loaded.
});
```

You can implement it like that:

```js
myClass.addFramework = function (name, onload) {
    var _script = document.createElement('script');
    _script.onload = function () {
        onload();
    }
    _script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') onload();
    }
    _script.src = myClass.FRAMEWORK_BASE + '/' + name + '.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_script);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using custom Events? Something like this:

```
var CustomEvent = function() {
    this.eventName = arguments[0];
    var eventAction = null;
    this.subscribe = function(fn) {
        eventAction = fn; // you can customize this to hold array of handlers
    }; 
    this.fire = function(sender, eventArgs) {
        if (eventAction != null) {
            eventAction(sender, eventArgs);
        } else {
            alert('No ' + mEventName + ' handler!');
        }
    };
};
```

Now you can define something like this:

```
var myEvent = new CustomEvent("Framework Loaded");
myEvent.subscribe(function(sender, eventArgs) {
    alert('Framework loaded! Hurray!');
    // jQuery goes here
});
```

and after loading framework for example jQuery you just do this:

```
myEvent.fire(null, { framework: 'jQuery' });
```

(you should put the code probably somewhere in XHR handler).

Also if you make it fire after DOM loaded then you can forget about jQuery's `$(document).ready(...)` wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your class has a jQuery dependancy, ideally you should not have that dependancy.

Nonetheless if you are looking for an easy way to load jQuery dynamically, maybe this would help:

```
function onReady(){
    // My Custom Ready state. lets go wild here.
}

if (typeof jQuery === undefined || jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.7.2') {

    var jScript = document.createElement('script');
    jScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    jScript.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js")

    //Run onReady() once jQuery and document have loaded
    jScript.onload = function () { //Add on load Event delegate
        //JQuery is Loaded!! so you can do whatever you want with it to deligate.
        $(document).ready(onReady)
    }; 
    jScript.onreadystatechange = function () { //Same thing but for IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded')(function () {
            //JQuery is Loaded!! so you can do whatever you want with it to deligate.
            $(document).ready(onReady)
        });
    } 

    // Append Script to the Head
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);

} else {
    // JQuery Exists so lets just use it
    $(document).ready(onReady);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery document.ready function basically does this:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
Javascript code goes here
}
```

Which has no dependencies on external libraries and will run your Javascript when the document has loaded.

You might also want to look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: I know - but i want to realize that i can use my js class in any project. Just one file, that handle all frameworks and other stuff - but except this i want to code my jQuery in the default way - but in this way i must realize that the hole javascript will be ignored until my class had finished the libaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this small library to execute script after loading: 
[Yepnope javascript loader](http://yepnopejs.com/)

Also you can download scripts via ajax call. And in success callback append it to the document and execute script's code. But this approach already used in Yepnope library.